# Navigator is not working properly in Stock chart for column type

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, navigator

The issue here is that the navigator is won't drag the entire width when I am selecting column type for stock chart. I am unable to select the last value 00:10 .

[My jsbin.](http://jsbin.com/erunew/1/edit)

```
navigator: {
    series: {
        type: "column",
        field: "Importance"
    },
    select: {
        from: "1970/01/01 00:00:00",
        to: "1970/01/01 00:02:13"
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This is looking an awful lot like a bug after some testing. You'll probably want to report it.

Comment: Definitely a bug.  I took the example from Kendo's demo page, http://demos.kendoui.com/dataviz/financial/index.html, changed the navigator type to 'column' and got the same behavior.  It seems to work correctly on all other navigator types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@NT3RP is correct, this is definitely a bug.  I took the example from Kendo's demo page, [demos.kendoui.com/dataviz/financial/index.html](http://demos.kendoui.com/dataviz/financial/index.html), changed the navigator's `type` property to `column` and saw the same behavior.  It seems to work correctly with all other navigator types.